# What does IOT mean in regards to SIGIOT?

Tags: linux, unix, history, terminology, signal

I've been looking around and I found that it was related to an abort call,  Something to do with an IOT trap, but any resource I find seems to assume you already know what that is.  Probably isn't important, but I saw it and was curious.  I suppose it could even just be arbitrary letters.

Answer (score 8):

#### What does IOT mean in regards to SIGIOT?

It stands for **input/output trap**.

> **Macro: int SIGABRT**
>
> This signal indicates an error detected by the program itself and reported by calling abort. See Aborting a Program.
>
> **Macro: int SIGIOT**
>
> Generated by the PDP-11 “iot” instruction. On most machines, this is just another name for SIGABRT.

Source [Program Error Signals](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Error-Signals.html)

---

#### PDP-11 Jump and subroutine instructions

> **Jump and subroutine instructions**
>
> - JMP (jump)
> - JSR (jump to subroutine)
> - RTS (return from subroutine)
> - MARK (support of stack clean-up at return)
> - EMT (emulator trap)
> - TRAP, BPT (breakpoint trap)
> - IOT (input/output trap)
> - RTI & RTT (return from interrupt)

Source [PDP-11 architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11_architecture)

Comment: Also mentioned (very briefly, and not explained) in [PDP-11 instruction reference](http://www.teach.cs.toronto.edu/~ajr/258/pdp11.pdf) (6-page PDF)